# in PHP how to integrate paypal for service business?

Tags: php, paypal

I created web for education institute. Then I want to get payment through paypal. So I use this code

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="amount">

    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
```

I want get payment for service business, but this will show product business. Please help me to solve this question? (it mean don't show quantity)

Comment: You mean to say that you are not able to show the item price and quantity on the PayPal checkout page?

Comment: yes,want to show course name and amount only.

Comment: The way you are using is correct only . You should pass the course name in item_name. So it should be : <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item description here "> . Rest of the things are fine . You will see the description, amount , quantity and total on the checkout page .

Comment: i don't want to show quantity

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to hide the quantity field . Even if you don't pass the quantity it will shown default to '1' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then I use this code.it will some good.

`<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">`

`<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">`

`<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />`

`<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="fee">`

`<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"/>`

`<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"/>`

`<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D"/>`

`<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"/>`

`<input type="hidden" name="sca" value="1"/>`

`<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>`

Comment: You can use this code as well . However it will be recurring payment rather than one time payment . If your business model requires recurring payments then you can go with it.

Comment: yes,it is not displayed quantity and item price in checkout .but it displayed paying circle.it becomes a problem.